# docker-compose does not forward the user

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

There is a problem with the docker-compose file.
The task is to run playbook ansible in docker-compose container. Mount local directory with playbooks/config/ssh to container and run playbook.
And in this case everything works. But when I add user forwarding, the container stops forwarding keys.
What am I doing wrong?

**Dockerfile:**

> ```
> FROM alpine:3.15.3
>
> RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache musl-dev openssl-dev make gcc
> python3 py3-pip py3-cryptography python3-dev RUN pip3 install cffi RUN
> pip3 install ansible RUN apk add --update openssh \ && rm  -rf /tmp/*
> /var/cache/apk/*
>
> WORKDIR /etc/ansible
> ```

**Working docker-compose:**

> ```
> version: "3.3"
>
> services:   
>     ansible:
>     build: .
>     volumes:
>       - ./inventory:/etc/ansible
>       - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
> ```

**Not working docker-compose**

```
version: "3.3"

services:
   ansible:
     build: .
     volumes:
         - ./inventory:/etc/ansible
         - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
     user: ${UID}:${GID}
```

**Last docker-compose i`ll run:**

> ```
> sudo UID=${UID} GID=${GID} docker-compose run --rm ansible
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Find solution

```
version: "2.3"

services:
  ansible:
    build: .
    user: ${UID}:${GID}
    volumes:
      - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/etc/group:ro
      - /home/${USER}/.ssh:/home/&{USER}/.ssh
```

Run:

```
UID="$(id -u)" GID="$(id -g)" USER="$(id -u -n)" docker-compose run --rm ansible
```